# Vue Composition API: Is there a better way in calling `emit` inside consumable file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

What is the correct way (or a better way) to access `emit` in the separated logic file?

This is what I did currently that works:

**foo.js**

```
export default (emit) => {
    const foo = () => { emit('bar') };
    return { foo };
}
```

Then on the consuming component:

```
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api';
import foo from './foo';

export default defineComponent({
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const { foo } = foo(emit);
    return { foo };
  }
});
```

But I wonder if there is a more appropriate way on doing this? Or is it a bad practice to call `emit` inside a consumable file?

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question, but `defineComponent` is now shipped with `vue`, so you should probably import from it. Unless you are using earlier version of Vue.

Comment: @YomS. thanks but yes, I'm aware of it. Currently doing this on NuxtJS/Vue 2, so that's why I use the separate vue/composition-api package.

Comment: Ah I see. What are you trying to achieve with this though? I mean if you mean to do some even hubs, you might want to look into [this migration guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/events-api.html#migration-strategy) on using external emitters.

Comment: Ohh I see, that looks good.. I think this will help in solving the problem to clean this up... Thanks!

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to your last question that you deleted few minutes ago? I mean this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65026253/object-is-possibly-null-on-a-refnull)

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes but not quite. I had to add a type like `subComponentRef: Ref<any> = ref(null);`, I know `any` is not the best, but since I don't know the right type for it yet, I have to use it for a moment. But the real weird problem about still getting error even if adding an `if else` is still I don't have an idea, maybe a TypeScript bug on some way.

Comment: please undelete it, I will give you some solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have found the solution, but in case you would try similar way (as originally asked in question), there's this option called [`getCurrentInstance`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance) that has an emitter (the Vue 2 plugin for Composition API [has one too](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/blob/d1ff9df0fe4d375421dc2574cc24e115b6a01347/src/runtimeContext.ts#L74)).

```js
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

export default () => {
  const { emit } = getCurrentInstance();

  const foo = () => {
    emit('bar');
  };

  return { foo };
}
```

But bear in mind that this will only work for calling functions/components that have the [`SetupContext`](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/blob/d1ff9df0fe4d375421dc2574cc24e115b6a01347/src/component/componentOptions.ts#L6).

### Edit

The above solution will work for Vue 3, yet with earlier version of Vue + the [Composition API plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api), there is but a slight difference: As with the rest of the [Instance Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Properties), you'll have to prefix it with `$` to become [`$emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit). (The following example now assumes Typescript as the target language, as mentioned on the comment).

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from '@vue/composition-api';

export default () => {
  // Ugly workaround, since the plugin did not have the `ComponentInstance` type exported. 
  // You could use `any` here, but that would defeat the purpose of having type-safety, won't it?
  // And we're marking it as `NonNullable` as the consuming components 
  // will most likely be (unless desired otherwise).
  const { $emit, ...context } = getCurrentInstance() as NonNullable<ReturnType<typeof getCurrentInstance>>;

  const foo = () => {
    $emit.call(context, 'bar');
  };

  return { foo };
}
```

For Vue 3's Composition API, however, they do have this [`ComponentInternalInstance`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/ca8276d1fa01c06fd63394a2c0d572581618ae3d/packages/runtime-core/src/component.ts#L196) interface exported.

P.S. It's probably best to stick to the old-school way of assigning the instance to a variable and do `context.$emit` or `vm.$emit` rather than having to explicitly specify a context for everything. I initially came up with this idea without realizing that those Instance Properties are probably meant for internal uses, which is not exactly the case with the next Composition API.

Comment: Thanks!, tried it but that exactly did not work on my case. I'm not sure if that will exactly work on Vue3, but since I'm using `@vue/composition-api` - it has to be `$emit` not `emit`. Also a `bonus` on using TS like me, you may encounter an error: `Property '$emit' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance` that is because it will only be populated on runtime. So you have to save it somewhere like: `const vm = (getCurrentInstance as any)();`, then call it like: `vm.$emit('bar');`

Comment: Maybe please update the answer with the issues I mentioned, clarify what works on V3 & what works on V2/composition-api so others will not get confused when I mark this as solved.

Comment: @rmondesilva Hey you're right about having to prefix it with `$` for the plugin. I edited my answer to explain that.

Comment: Saved my 5 days!